# ScrollView overflowing its FrameLayout parent

Tags: android, android-layout, scrollview, android-framelayout, overlapping

I have a complicated `LinearLayout` (vertical) with a `FrameLayout` above some other stuff (a `TextView` and an `EditText` box). The `FrameLayout` contains two things: a) a map and b) a `ScrollView` containing a semi-transparent `LinearLayout` that 'overlays' the map. The ScrollView is initially `GONE`, but I render it visible programmatically. I also programmatically add Views into the `LinearLayout` embedded in the `ScrollView`.

The FrameLayout dimensions are set using `onMeasure()` so that the height and width are equal. This make the `FrameLayout` take up the top portion of the device screen while the `TextView` and `EditText` fit below.

```
public static class MyFrameLayout extends FrameLayout {

    public FrameLayoutWithMap(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMeasure(int widthSpec, int heightSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthSpec, heightSpec);
        int size = Math.min(getMeasuredWidth(), getMeasuredHeight());
        setMeasuredDimension(size, size);
    }
}
```

Everything actually works great in the beginning. However, when I add enough Views to the `LinearLayout` embedded in the `ScrollView` the ScrollView will eventually extend *behind* the `TextView` below the `FrameLayout`. In other words, the ScrollView overflows its `FrameLayout` parent, the bottom of which is then hidden. As I continue to add Views to the `LinearLayout` embedded in the `ScrollView` the `ScrollView` will eventually start scrolling. It appears as though this happens once the `ScrollView` is the height of the device screen.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activityRoot"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#323232"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <FrameLayout
        class="com.myapp.main.MyFrameLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#070707" >

        <com.myapp.main.MapView
            android:id="@+id/map"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/overlayScrollView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:fillViewport="false"
            android:visibility="gone" >
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/overlayLinearLayout"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"                
                android:padding="1dp"       
                android:background="#AA000000" >
            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>

    </FrameLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvMessage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="14sp" />

    <EditText android:id="@+id/entry"
        android:background="@drawable/entry_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:lines="1"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:hint="@string/entry" />

</LinearLayout>
```

What I would like to happen is for the `ScrollView` to start scrolling as soon as it's the height of its `FrameLayout` parent. Put another way, I'd like for the `ScrollView` to remain *contained* within its `FrameLayout` parent.

[image]

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: The reason is unclear but you can try removing the visibility from the xml and doing it via your activity. That may help

Comment: Thanks, but the visibility of the `ScrollView` is not a problem. It's visible. I've added a graphic to help illustrate the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:**

The new [ConstraintLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout.html) library gives you fine-grained control of how your views are sized in relation to the parent and to other views. It also supports aspect ratios, so you can (for instance) force a view to always be square.

**Original response:**

The problem is how you are measuring your special FrameLayout. When you call `super.onMeasure()`, this view and all of its children will measure themselves according to the measure specs given. After that, you constrain the dimensions of this view, but none of its children are aware of this; only this view and its *parent* are aware of this. Its children have measured themselves thinking the size of this view is not constrained by your extra call to `setMeasuredDimension()`.

Calling `super.onMeasure()` again will force its children to measure themselves again, thereby informing them of the new size.

```
@Override
public void onMeasure(int widthSpec, int heightSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(widthSpec, heightSpec);
    int size = Math.min(getMeasuredWidth(), getMeasuredHeight());
    int spec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(size, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
    super.onMeasure(spec, spec);
}
```

Note this will cause this view and all its children to measure twice as many times with each measure pass, so it might not be the most performant approach, but it will accomplish what you want.

Comment: Genius. Removing the first `super.onMeasure()` created a mess, so I'll live with the performance hit, which frankly will probably be pretty insignificant. Thanks!

Comment: @karakuri Is there any other way to do it that is via XML.

Comment: @SachinSharma The new [ConstraintLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout.html) library supports aspect ratios on views.